# SASS: Is it a good practice to write Nested CSS using SASS?

Tags: html, css, sass, nested

In sass it is possible to write nested css like this:

```css
#A{
  .InnerContainerAA{
    p{
      font-size: 20px;
    }
  }
  .InnerContainerAB{
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
  <div class="InnerContainerAA">
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>
  <div class="InnerContainerAB">
    <button>Hover to change color</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way, both HTML and CSS(SASS) follow the same format.

However,

1. Is it a good practice to do so? (If no, please explain)
2. What are the performance implications of writing in this nested
   manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is it a good practice to do so? (If no, please explain)**

Yes it is, it is the way scss is meant to be written.

**What are the performance implications of writing in this nested manner?**

None because your scss compiler will compile it to plain css and that wil be used by the browser